# What is the purpose of QueueMessageHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

What is the purpose of QueueMessageHandler in the code pasted below? The queueMessageHandler doesn't seem to perform much in the example below.

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(queueMessageHandler());
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
    return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
}


@Bean
public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler() {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    queueMessageHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync());
    QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler = queueMessageHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
    return queueMessageHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueueMessageHandler` extends [`AbstractMethodMessageHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/AbstractMethodMessageHandler.html):

> Abstract base class for HandlerMethod-based message handling. Provides most of the logic required to discover handler methods at startup, find a matching handler method at runtime for a given message and invoke it.
>
> Also supports discovering and invoking exception handling methods to process exceptions raised during message handling.